# g++ does not find my header file?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a simple program in C++ on a raspberry pi using g++. But I keep getting that the header file does not exist. I an CERTAIN that the file does exist and that it is also in the same folder as the source files.

Does anyone have any idea? I have covered the first 4 pages of a dozen of Google seaches with no luck.

The command I am using when in the correct folder is:

`g++ -v -std=c++0x test.cpp timehandler.cpp -o Test`

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "timehandler.h"

int main ()
{
    TimeHandler tOne("2015-12-12 20:00");
    TimeHandler tTwo("2015-12-12 21:00");

    cout << tOne.timeDiff(tTwo) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

timehandler.cpp:

```
#include "timehandler.h"

using namespace std;

//Converts a timestring with "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" to a time_t
TimeHandler::TimeHandler(std::string timeString)
{
  strptime(timeString.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &mTimeInfo);
  mTime = mktime(timeInfo);
}

int TimeHandler::getTime()
{
  return mTime;
}

double TimeHandler::timeDiff(TimeHandler t)
{
    return difftime(this->getTime(),t.getTime());
}
```

timehandler.h:

```
#ifndef TIMEHANDLER_H
#define TIMEHANDLER_H

#include <string>
#include <time>

class TimeHandler
{
public:
    //Constructor
    TimeHandler(std::string timeString);

    //Public functions
    time_t getTime();
    double timeDiff(TimeHandler t);

private:
   //Private members
   struct tm mTimeInfo;
   time_t mTime;
};

#endif
```

Comment: _"I an CERTAIN that the file does exist and that it is also in the same folder as the source files."_ Apparently not! Can you prove this with `ls` output? Is the file readable?

Comment: Yes,  all files are visible in output with ls. I can also edit them using eg nano.

Comment: add `-I.` to the compilation command

Comment: Is this a upper-case  / lower-case issue ?

Comment: Prove it. _Show us_. You're missing something and we can't tell you what it is unless you provide us with the evidence you're misinterpreting to draw your conclusions.

Comment: Also, show us _the actual error_.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to compile your code showed that there are several errors:

1. Inconsistent return type:

   in your cpp file you have:

   ```
   int TimeHandler::getTime()
   ```

   but this should be like in you header file:

   ```
   time_t TimeHandler::getTime()
   ```
2. I also had to change the `#include <time>` to `ctime` (or `time.h`):

   ```
   #include <ctime>
   ```
3. The parameter for last line of the constructor `int TimeHandler::getTime()` was incorrect, and should be:

   ```
   mTime = mktime(&mTimeInfo);
   ```
4. In the main you are missing the namespace `std` for `cout` and `endl` (or `using namespace std`):

   ```
   std::cout << tOne.timeDiff(tTwo) << std::endl;
   ```

Comment: Not sure how any of this is relevant to the question, although it may suggest that the OP isn't actually compiling the code they think they're compiling.

Comment: The OP is mentions that "the header file does not exist", and when I tried to compile the code it complained about `#include <time>`, although it is true that is probably that he/she refers to the header file `timehandler.h`.

Comment: Hmm, good point! Except for in the title, the OP never actually said `timehandler.h` was the one broken!

Comment: Thank You, agold! Although the compiler did complain that it could not find timehandler.h, when I did correct the errors you pointed out it worked. Strange way to display the errors.

I have only used Xcode and compiled C++ to use locally on my Mac before. Now I am using atom as a text editor to remotely edit the files on a raspberry pi and compiling the code using g++. Is there a better set on tools?

Comment: You probably should be able to compile it on your Mac, and then on your pi as long as you use compatible compiler and libraries. But this is a new question, also see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.